# Running bash script using gradle android studio before androidTests

Tags: node.js, android-studio, localhost, android-instrumentation

I have android project using java which uses a nodejs server hosted on heruko. What I want is to run a local server before androidTest(instrument test), I have tried writing batch(bash*) file and running my server as an external tool.

That doesn't work async and stops the test. Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

This is how serverScript.bat looks:

`cd C:\intern.apply
start node server test`

---

### Update v1:

I found a way to run my bash* file from gradle. But there is 1 problem, it always run, I want it to run only when someone runs androidTests (robitium/acceptance tests) from android studio. Right now I have this task in gradle.build (Project:AppName)

```
task mytask() {
    ant.exec(
        executable: 'serverScript.bat',
        spawn: true
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your bash (not batch) file, have you tried running the server in background?

```
run_server & --> will be processed in background and the script continues
run_tests
stop_server
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I want to be able to run tests through android studio (the green arrow) or by clicking run :)